# in the latex i want to remove the number that appears beside the reference ( Latin numbers)

Tags: beamer, page-breaking

In HFU Beamer Theme from the overleaf cite. In the latex presentation, I want to remove the number that appears beside the reference (Latin numerals).

```
\newcommand{\enumref}[1]
{{%
  \leavevmode\unskip
 \def\insertenumlabel{\ref{#1}}
 \usebeamertemplate*{enumerate item}%
}}
—————————————————-
\section{References}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
 \begin{thebibliography}{}
 \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[book]
   \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[article]
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. Also note that a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem is useful for questions like this. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: Due to the lack of a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), your question currently is unfortunately somewhat unclear. I nevertheless guess, that adding `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}` resolved the issue.